# Braintree vs Paypal for direct payment like stripe

Tags: node.js, paypal, braintree

In my country Stripe is not supported, and it is really frustrating because it is the easiest to use for the payment gateway. Now I have other choices like Braintree and paypal.

So technically the user can enter his credit/debit card and straight away purchase the item.

Which one is easier to use Braintree or paypal for Direct payment like Stripe. I found Braintree and paypal docs are kinda confusing. If anyone could direct me to the right direction.

Comment: I'd suggest brainpal.

Comment: Brainpal, could you show me the docs. Thanks

Comment: What country are you in?

Answer (score 0):

If Stripe isn't supporting you for direct credit card processing then PayPal and Braintree probably won't either.

You would have other options with them, though, like PayPal Wallet payments, within which people could indeed pay with a credit card.

Or depending on the country, you might be able to provide "guest checkout" which allows people to enter a credit card without creating or signing in to a PayPal account, but the payment still happens on the PayPal pages.

Answer (score 0):

Partially in response to Andrew. That is incorrect, PayPal and stripe are completely different in the aspects of the businesses they support. Often times if you fill out a merchant application via PayPal you can be verified for their Pro Payments System. As long as your business meets PayPal's TOS, they will almost always grant access to their card processor.

Stripe is still growing, PayPal is grown.